# Why does my Selenium URL_to_be statement not work?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Selenium does not seem to register that I manually go to the publish0x.com page.
Does anyone know a solution?

My goal is to manually do the captcha at the login page and afterwards, when I log in and land on the main page I want the script to resume.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def waitForLoad(inputXPath):
    Wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inputXPath)))

email = '
password = '

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
## options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/vadim/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser")
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get('https://www.publish0x.com/login')
waitForLoad('//*[@id="email"]')
E_Mail_vak = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
E_Mail_vak.send_keys(email)
Pass_vak = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
Pass_vak.send_keys(password)
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "recaptcha")]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
Captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
Captcha.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500)
wait.until(EC.url_to_be("publish0x.com"))
driver.get('https://www.publish0x.com/newposts')
post = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main > div.infinite-scroll > div:nth-child(1) > div.content')
title = post.find_element_by_css_selector('h2 > a').text
author = post.find_element_by_css_selector('p.text-secondary > small:nth-child(4) > a').text
title.click()
slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tipslider"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of, one by adding an ***Input statement*** like this:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')#For properly seeing the outputs
input("Please do the captcha and press any key...)
```

In this way, the user would complete the data and then **press any key** for the script to continue.

The other way is by adding a `try` and `except` statement.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("some-element")

except NoSuchElementException:
    #do something like
    print("Captcha Failed or Incomplete...")
```

In this, **replace** the element id "some-element" with any element that is present and **only present after the user logs in**, for e.g elements like *Profile_nav* or *Settings* are only present when someone logs in. So if the element doesn't exist then it would mean that the **user didn't complete the captcha.**